# Keeping Subshell running in the background

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to run a script in the background using '&' at the end of the command, but apparently, it isn't working out.

This is the issue I am facing. To use a paid simulation software, the provider has instructed me to run a certain script to enable license access. I am to leave this open and start the software from another terminal (in batch mode without GUI, since I am using a supercomputing cluster).

Trouble is, I can only send one script to the scheduler in the head node (which I am connected through ssh), and the job is forwarded to one of the compute nodes. So instead of starting a new terminal to run the software, I attempted to run the provided script in the background using '&'. This didn't work out. It appears the connection to the license server is getting closed as soon as it's started with this method.

```
./script1.sh &
```

Using

```
xterm -e sh script1.sh
```

to open it in another terminal gave the following error-

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 

xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(The question was posted by me, nearly three years ago. I dare say I've become better at shell scripting in the meantime - I ran across a similar problem recently and was reminded of this question once again.)

So as a previous comment suggested, all I had to use was `screen`. But since I did not have access to keyboard shortcuts as I was running the code on a cluster, I wasn't able to use Ctrl+A to get back to the body of my main script as the answer suggested.

Well, all I had to do was start `screen` in the background like this:

Start a screen with the name sample-screen in detached mode from the main script.

`screen -S sample-screen -d -m`

Ask the detached screen to run a comand without re-attaching it.

`screen -S sample-screen -p 0 -X stuff "./script1.sh & ^M"`

`^M` is the return character. Akin to pressing enter in the detached screen.

To kill the screen on exiting the script-

`screen -XS sample-screen quit`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the job you submit needs to be one which performs both tasks.

```
#!/bin/sh
license </dev/null >license.out 2>&1 &
license_pid=$!
simulator
kill $license_pid
wait $license_pid
```

This saves standard output and standard error from the licensing process to a file so you can `tail` that to see what it wants to tell you if there should be a problem.

Comment: I have tried precisely this. It appears the process for running the license in the background is getting closed immediately.
'kill $license_pid' gave the error 'No such process'

Comment: Sometimes you can fix this by redirecting standard input to `/dev/null`.

Comment: 'sh license_script.sh /dev/null 2>&1'

Indeed did do the trick. Thanks @BobEager

Comment: That's standard output, which I was going to suggest next!

Comment: Updated the answer; thanks for comments. I'm hesitant to discard error messages and doubt that it's necessary or even useful.

Comment: Hi again! It appears I was mistaken. The software ran only because the license script was running in the background on the head node. Suppressing the output with `/dev/null`  did not help, unfortunately.

When I try to see the background processes, with `jobs` it shows the licensing process as 'stopped'.

Sorry for the (unintended) confusion.

Comment: Updated to save output as well as stderr to a file, though uncertain whether that woud bring any relief.

Comment: Hi again,

I finally ventured into what was inside the so-called license script. Turned out, at the heart of it, it was doing an ssh into another server. (I guess this was to be expected, after all). I modified the ssh line in the license script as per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199505/7277918). I did not have to suppress the output to `/dev/null` or ignore the errors after this slight modification. Thanks again so much @tripleee, @Bob Eager!

Answer (score 2):

Can you not `ssh` to the node, then start a copy of `screen`? Have a look at the manual page. It allows you to have two or more sessions as (effectively) subprocesses of your `ssh` login shell.

So, `ssh` as normal. Start `screen`. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>c</kbd> to create a second screen. Start the license thing in that screen, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to get back to the original screen. Start your application there. Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> sequence to switch back and forth if needed.

To detach without terminating, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>; to reattach later on (even after terminating your `ssh` session and logging back in, use `screen -x`.

Comment: If things are running in batch on a node with no interactive terminal access, I don't think this will work.

Comment: Yes, but he **doesn't want to detach**. He just needs two sessions on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, I do not have interactive terminal access. Which is why I cannot use screen or similar alternatives which require Ctrl-A or other shortcuts. Thanks,

Comment: Ah, it wasn't entirely clear. Looks as if tripleee's answer is the one you want.